# My practical Inner scroll conundrum

Tags: usability, scrolling

I have a table that needs to be scrolled (see below, and sorry for the foreign language). The table shows real estate transactions which can have a large initial set of results.

Because there are other content on the page before the table, the page itself also scrolls. I now have a classic inner scroll problem. The user scrolls the page and when he reaches the table, the page seems to suddenly stop scrolling as the said table starts to scroll instead.

I was thinking maybe I should set a timer which disables the table scrolling for a bit after each page scroll event, but was wondering if you think this is a reasonable solution and if anyone can share other ideas or directions.:)

[image: table with scroll bar]

Comment: Can you remove the inner scroll and have the table make the page longer? What is below the table that users need to get to?

Comment: @NathanRabe Below it (and above it) are other pieces of information (e.g. neighborhood info, similar assets, map, ext...). On one hand the number of transactions can be quite long and on the other hand people like to browse it, so removing it isn't quite an option)

Comment: Not a duplicate but an interesting related discussion: [Should scrolling in a textbox overflow to scrolling a page?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/36556/should-scrolling-in-a-textbox-overflow-to-scrolling-a-page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would recommend pagination with filtering and sorting. Don't scroll the transactions table- fix it to about a dozen rows. But then provide a way to sort the columns, and even better allow the user to filter down the visible rows by some criteria.  Finally, provide pagination if they really really want to view more rows.

Users never (well rarely) actually want to review hundreds of rows, so ask yourself **what transactions do my users care about**? and then provide the functionality that allows the users to get to those rows as quickly as possible.